# DownloadFile The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I have my downloader downloading files and it runs fine for the most part, but ever so often it start throwing exceptions. The exception is:

```
[11:15:34 a.m.] >> [Error StartDownloadFile] An exception occurred during a WebClient request. | System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'A:\Users\user\downloads\test\file.extention' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
```

The code I am using for this is:

```
while (true)
            {
    try
        {
            downloadUrl = new Uri(result.url);
            var fileName = dir + "\\" + escapeFilename(result.passedFileName) + ".extention";

            while (true)
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(downloadUrl, fileName);
                }

                long fileSize = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
                if (fileSize < 1000)
                {
                    Log("[Error] " + result.passedFileName + " failed, re-downloading");
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("[Error StartDownloadFile] " + ex.Message + " | " + ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

Now looking at other asking similar questions their fix was to use garbage collection or something along those lines, but since I'm using WebClient DownloadFile I assume that is build in. So I'm not sure what is throwing this exception and how to fix it

Comment: Did you tried to close your probably running instances in TaskManager? Are you running in debbuging mode in VS? Check for sure there are no instances left, then try - if error didnt disappered - restart your computer

Comment: Are you perhaps attempting to download a file to an existing filename, and an existing file lock is preventing you overwriting it with the new file?

Comment: @Toumash I am running in debug mode and there are no other instances of the program running. Restarting didn't do anything

Comment: @RJLohan Possible but I dont think so since all the files its download *Should* have a "unique" name

Comment: I think that @RJLohan is probably correct.  Can you try testing this out with filenames on the file system that are DEFINITELY unique?  Maybe something like: `var fileName = dir + "\\" + string.Format(@"{0}.extention", Guid.NewGuid());`

Comment: Well would you look at that... There are 2 items out of the 1060 that have the same name..
When I changed their names it worked. I guess one of you can use that as the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the DownloadFile() function returns before the OS//framework unlocks the file. 
*This may explain why a garbage collection seems to solve the problem : it simply  delays the access to the file.*

In that case, a work around would be :

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) // time out = 20*100 ms = 2 seconds
try 
{ 
  // your code accessing to the file
  i=999 ; // exit loop 
} 
catch { system.thread.threading.Sleep(100) ; }
```

Comment: It turns out that, it was 2 items out of the 1060 that have the same name which is why it was giving me the exception. Although your answer would help other users who may have a similar problem